# list of block level elements gets split in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, internet-explorer-6

I am trying to make a table-like calendar page, using fixed width and height block level elements. There is an outer container, which sets the width, and the cells get aligned by float: left. It works well in every browser, except in IE6, where the list gets split after the 29th element.

If I make the outside container a bit more wide (by at least 3 pixels) the problem gets fixed in IE6. Because the elements are more than 3 pixels wide, it doesn't change how the page looks. But I really don't understand why it happens, and what should I do not to make it happen.

I tried IE7.js, but it didn't help.

I know IE6 is such a buggy old browser, but while my sites are simple I prefer making them IE6 compatible.

[link to the page in question](http://asztal.brainhurt.net/naptar.php)

[image: image of the bug]

Comment: You can put in if statements in the HTML to load a different set of styles for IE6. This page can show you how to do that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by adding this to the bottom of `style.css`:

```
/* IE6 hack */
* html #naptar-list a, * html #naptar-list div {
    width: 77px
}
```

This works by using the [Star HTML hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_HTML_hack) to feed to only IE6 the declaration `width: 77px` (`1px` less than the actual width), which in my testing, fixed the problem: I'm not entirely sure why.

Comment: Thanks, I never knew why do many sites have * html lines in their css. I actually had to use '* html #naptar-list{width: 549px;}' as the width: 77 modified the look of the site.